# Замена нужного символа во всей строке

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11

Доброго времени суток!

Нужно построчно прочитать текст из файла, заменить код буквы "а" на 3 (грубо и проще говоря превратить в "г") и перезаписать в файл.

Всё сделал, кроме замены символа в строке, но не могу понять в чём ошибка. В цикле просто меняет все символы в тексте на нужную.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string> // подключаем библиотеку строк
#include <fstream> // подключаем библиотеку файлов

using namespace std; // используем стандартное пространство имен

int main() {

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru"); // добавляем работу с Русским Языком

    string s; // сюда будем класть считанные строки
    ifstream tisbi1("tisbi1.txt"); // файл из которого читаем
    ofstream tisbi2("tisbi2.txt"); // файл куда будем записывать

    while (getline(tisbi1, s)) // пока не достигнут конец файла класть очередную строку в переменную (s)
    { 
        cout << s << endl; // выводим на экран
        for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++) // создаём цикл прохода посимвольно в строке
        {
            if (s[i] = 'а')
            {
                s[i] += 3; // Заменяем код буквы по ASCII на 3
            }

            // ЗДЕСЬ НУЖНО УВЕЛИЧИТЬ НА 3 КОД БУКВЫ, НО ЦИКЛ ВЫШЕ ЗАМЕНЯЕТ ВСЕ БУКВЫ. НЕ ПОЙМУ ПОЧЕМУ.
        }
        tisbi2 << s << endl; // Записываем строку в файл
    }
        
    
    tisbi2.close(); // закрываем файл чтобы не повредить его
    tisbi1.close(); // закрываем файл чтобы не повредить его

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `s[i] = 'а'` -> `s[i] == 'а'`

Comment: `s[i] = 'а'` -> `'а' == s[i]` пишите константы слева

Comment: Всем большое спасибо! Столько часов сидел не мог разобраться, а тут такая легкая синтаксическая ошибка. Вот что значит взглянуть с другой стороны. Сразу помогли)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ошибка кроется в этом куске кода:

```cpp
if (s[i] = 'а')
{
    s[i] += 3; // Заменяем код буквы по ASCII на 3
}
```

Для равенства используется **два** знака равенства, не одно — отсюда неверная работа программы. Напишите `s[i] == 'a'` вместо `s[i] = 'a'`, и программа должна заработать.

Comment: Большое спасибо!